# Auto incrementing a counter in a table

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am trying to auto number lines in a table which I got to work by using:

```
/* Set the Serial counter to 0 */
{ counter-reset: Serial;  }

/* Set the serial number counter to 0 */

.css-serial {
  counter-reset: serial-number; }

/* Increment the serial number counter */
.css-serial td:first-child:before {
  counter-increment: serial-number;
  /* Display the counter */  
  content: counter(serial-number); }

<a href="http://www.phoenixcomm.net/~harrison/tmp/questions/Code1.207-05-16.html">My table code</a><br>
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/NNL2n.png"></a><br>
```

This works like a champ but I have one small issue when it gets to one of my separators. As shown in items #7, #10. How can I stop it from numbering the separator?

```
<tr><_td colspan=2><HR 30%></td></tr>
```

Comment: Please post some more code, specifically the markup.   Unfortunately there is not much we can do with a picture.

Answer (score 1):

Just guessing since the information above is incomplete and I assume the underscore is a typo, but

```
.css-serial td:not([colspan="2"]):first-child::before {
  counter-increment: serial-number;
  content: counter(serial-number); 
}
```